# Responsive image not aligning properly on mobile device

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have an image on a page that is aligned right via the following CSS

http://jsfiddle.net/jdp3Z/

I'd like for the image to align to the left when viewed on a mobile device (especially in Landscape mode. I try the following code:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 568px) {
img {
    float: left;
}
}
```

I guess that's not enough, because that doesn't seem to do the trick. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the right selector in this case `img.image-right` because the class make it more specific than just `img` then you can't override the float. Try this:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 568px) {
   img.image-right {
    float: left;
   }
}
```

Check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/jdp3Z/1/ resize the window.

Comment: So, i just didn't go far enough in... nice. Perfect, that did it! Thank you.